# Defining a branch of a logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis

Write down a branch of $log(z+i)$ which is holomorhpic in the plane with ${z: Re z = 0, Im z < 1}$ removed.

Do I just need to say that $log((1-i)+i) = 0$?  Is this enough for a definition?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To define the branch, you should explicitly define such holomorphic $f(r, \varphi)$ that $ e^{f(r, \varphi)} = re^{i\varphi} + i$

The answer would be $f(z) = \log|z+i| + i \arg (z + i)$, $\arg|z+i| \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}\right)$. To be more accurate, you could try to present $\arg (z + i)$ in terms of $\arg z$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(z)=1/(z+i)$ it has a single pole with residue 1 at $z=-i$. On the given domain there is no cycle containing $-i$ i.e. no cycle has a non zero winding number around $-i$ . So $\int_{0}^{z} f(\zeta) d\zeta $ is defined. This integral is a branch of $log(z+i)$ on the given domain.